# Specify time to live for a tomcat session?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

There is the session timeout setting:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

which control how long an inactive session stays valid.

Is it possible in addition to specify how long a session can live at all? To specify a "time to live" or a "max age" after which the user is forced to login again?

It is possible to do this with a tomcat configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this (inside session-config):

```
<cookie-config>
    <max-age>VALUE</max-age>
</cookie-config>
```